# Contact Name field from Quote to be used in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

I want to use the below contact field " contact name" ( API name " contact"), from Quote object in the process builder.

[image]

But i am not able to find this field which can be used. I can see contact ID, or contact ID > first name , last name. which are not working.
My need is, if this field " contact name" is blank, then it wont fill certain criteria ( ship to address , will not reflect from the Contact Name) . Can anyone plz suggest how shall i make the criteria as this field should be null ? Thanks

Comment: Why does checking if ContactId = null not work for you?

Comment: Hi Eric, nope this is not working.

Comment: I tried also, Contact ID > First Name/ Last name alsso not worked.

Comment: To mention, for the above null, i took, ContactId > doesnt equal> global constant null. If i have to take somthing else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact Name field is nothing but `Contact Id` (lookup).

You have to check if that `Contact Id` is null.

[image: contact name blank]